# Have to require the same file twice, how to get around this?

Tags: php, oop

I am having to require a Class file twice. Is there anyway to get around this? I have a class called Book. There is one main page that needs the class Book because it creates an object of the object of the book. There is a javascript file that uses ajax to load a script which saves the edited book object Here is flow of events that requires me to require the Class file twice:

1. There is one main page that requires the Book class because it will create a Book object and display information about that book. This page has a save button.
2. There is a javascript file that uses AJAX to load a PHP script which saves the edited book object.
3. The save script also has to require the Book class because it needs to load the same object. (cannot actually pass a PHP object through AJAX)

First of all, this does not even work. When I require the Book class in the save script, it fails. Second of all, is there a better way to do this because I have to require the Book class twice.

Comment: Strangely these sound like separate scripts, but have you tried using `require_once()` ? Since HTTP is stateless, the ajax call to the second PHP script has nothing to do with the first PHP page that presented the page.  My bet is, the error has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The require is faulty in the save script file. It works in the main page PHP. I am pretty sure that the path is correct in the save script is correct: require_once("../classes/BookClass.php");

Comment: pretty sure?  why aren't you absolutely sure?  seems a pretty simple path to verify...

Comment: I am 100% sure. I am using absolute paths and printed it out and loaded it, and it is correct.

Comment: It seems like you're confused. To the user it may seem to be one page, but to PHP, it's two completely separate requests. Whatever code you're using to load the Book on the main page cannot magically tell the AJAX script what to load. They are two separate objects. You must save the Book's ID (or whatever construction details you use) in the page's JavaScript, then use that script to tell the AJAX PHP which book to load.

Answer (score 0):

[`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) should give you what you need.

Having said that (after re-reading your question), the two scripts that you mention seem to be completely separate.. So..

*How* is the AJAX include failing? What error are you seeing?

Comment: The error in the save script is that any code that appears after the require is not executed. I placed an echo before and after the require to the class file, and only the echo before the require executes.

Comment: @egidra then you need to change the logging level so you see the actual error.

Comment: Sounds like there's something wonky going on in your class include file. I'd recommend stepping through it with `dbg` to figure out exactly what's going wrong and change your logging level.

Comment: How do I change the logging level?

Comment: @egidra At the top of the script you can put: `error_reporting(-1);` or you can edit php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `require_once()` to force your scripts to use existing resources. As far as an AJAX call to a PHP page which requires your Book class, there's nothing you can do to use the class instantiated by the parent page unless you store it in memcache or something because as far as your server is concerned it is a new request.

Comment: Does the require_once('BookClass.php') go inside of the main php file or the save php file? or both?